# Configure processing server role with config patches

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-xdb

The Sitecore documentation provides some pretty clear instructions on how to configure a Sitecore instance as a processing server:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/xdb_configuration/configure_a_processing_server

However, many of those steps require enabling/disabling of files manually on the installed server. Has anybody seen or built a patch file (similar to SwitchMasterToWeb) that can disable/enable the appropriate functionality as a patch? I would rather not touch the default Sitecore install and instead rely on automated deployment of configuration patches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody else winds up looking for this, I've posted some work up on GitHub for patch files for a variety of versions for 8.0:

https://github.com/jst-cyr/Sitecore-Role-Configs

The patches there will do the 'disable/enable/change' for authoring, delivery, or processing. I don't have one for the reporting server.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen this as a patch and not sure if its possible to do this with just one patch (would love to be proved wrong), but for something like this I've used a Powershell script.

I set up Octopus Deploy to run a Powershell script step after deploy to disable files and change settings if patch files can't do the job.

I can highly recommend the Powercore tools for this kind of thing.

https://github.com/adoprog/Sitecore-PowerCore/tree/master/Framework/ConfigUtils

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore has evaluated POC for same. At this point of time applciable for Sitecore CMS 8.1 rev. 160302 (Update-2). See here-
https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Configuration-Roles